# Finding all unique combinations of columns of pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, deep-learning

I have a data balancing problem at hand wherein I have images which have multiple classes i.e. each image can have multiple class or one class. I have the label file which has all the classes named from A to G and fn(image name) as the columns. Each column has a value 0 or 1,wherein 0 means that class is absent in image and 1 means that particular class is present in the image. Now, I want to subset the dataframe in such a manner that I get different dataframes each with combinations of different classes [image: Labels dataframe]

The issue is if I use the multiple conditions with the dataframe command such as (here pp is used to denote dataframe  :

```
pp_A_B=pp[(pp['A']==1) & (pp['B']==1) & (pp['C']==0) & (pp['D']==0) & (x['E']==0) & (x['F']==0) &(pp['G']==0)]
```

Here,pp_A_B gives me the dataframe having images which have only A and B classes.

I will have to write multiple variables to know about the various combinations.Kindly help how can we automate it to get all the possible combinations in a faster manner.

Comment: I am not sure if I understood you correctly. You **just** want all possible combinations of your columns or do you want also all possible combinations as dataframes, meaning using possible combinations to filter the data frame. And what should your output look like? Do you want a list of data frames? Do you want several defined data frame like pp_X if only X=1 for all columns in X?

Comment: @ko3 Yes I want the count as well as each dataframe having distinct combinations. For Example, separate dataframe having A and B class, separate dataframe having B and C class, separate dataframe having A,B,C,D class......etc. each data frame having distinct possible combinations.

Answer (score 1):

Hi you should use the `groupyby` and `get_group` methods to extract the desired elements.

Here is an example if you are trying to get datas where A = 0 & B= 0 :

```py
#Simulation of your datas
nb_rows = 10000
nb_colums = 5
df_array = np.random.randint(0,2, size =(nb_rows, nb_colums))
df = pd.DataFrame(df_array)
df.columns = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]
df["infos"] = [f"Exemples of data {i}" for i in range(len(df))]
```

[image]

**UPDATE :**

And now the use of the mentioned methods :

```py
df.groupby(["A", "B"]).get_group((0, 0))
```

[image]

Here you easily find all the data that meet A = 0 & B = 0.

Now you can iterate thought all of your targeted columns combinations this way :

```py
columns_to_explore = ["A", "B", "C"]
k = [0]*len(columns_to_explore)
for i in range(2**len(columns_to_explore)):
    i_binary = str(bin(i)[2:])
    i_binary = "".join(["0" for _ in range(len(columns_to_explore)-len(i_binary))]) + i_binary
    list_values = [int(x) for x in i_binary]
    df_selected = df.groupby(columns_to_explore).get_group(tuple(list_values))
    #Do something then ...
```

Comment: Perroud I agree with the implementation above but still for each combination I will have to change the value of zeros or ones in get_group  df.groupby(["A", "B"]).get_group((0, 0))

Comment: I just updated the code to iterate thought every combination

Answer (score 0):

Let us suppose you have the following data frame:

```py
import pandas as pd
import random


attr = [0, 1]
N = 10000
rg = range(N)

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'A': [random.choice(attr) for i in rg],
        'B': [random.choice(attr) for i in rg],
        'C': [random.choice(attr) for i in rg],
        'D': [random.choice(attr) for i in rg],
        'E': [random.choice(attr) for i in rg],
        'F': [random.choice(attr) for i in rg],
        'G': [random.choice(attr) for i in rg],
    }
)
```

and that you want to store all data frame combinations in a list. Then, you can write the following function to get all indices that correspond to the same combination of `0` and `1`:

```py
import random
from numba import njit

@njit
def _get_index_combinations(possible_combinations, values):
    index_outpus = []
    for combination in possible_combinations:
        mask = values == combination
        _temp = [i for i in range(len(mask)) if mask[i].all()]
        index_outpus.append(_temp)
    return index_outpus

possible_combinations = df.drop_duplicates().values
index_outpus = _get_index_combinations(possible_combinations, df.values)
```

Finally, you can decompose the data frame in chunks by iterating over all index combinations:

```py
sliced_dfs = [df.loc[df.index.isin(index)] for index in index_outpus]
```

If you then, for instance, run

```py
print(sliced_dfs[0])
```

you will get a query for one possible combination.

#### Note:

You can even go further an really create several data frames (not stored in a list) for all possible combinations. If you go dirty and use something like this:

```py
col_names = "ABCDEFG"
final_output = {"all_names": [], "all_querys": []}
for numerator, i in enumerate(possible_combinations):
    df_name = ""
    col_pos = np.where(i)[0]
    for pos in col_pos:
        df_name += col_names[pos]
    final_output["all_names"].append(f"df_{df_name}")
    query_code = f"df_{df_name} = df.loc[df.index.isin({index_outpus[numerator]})]"
    final_output["all_querys"].append(query_code)
    exec(query_code)
```

It creates you a dictionary named `final_output`. There, the names of all created data frames are stored. For example:

```py
{'all_names': ['df_ABG', 'df_G', 'df_AC', ...], 'all_querys': [...]}
```

You can then just print all frames in `all_names`, for example `df_ABG`, which returns you:

```py
      A  B  C  D  E  F  G
0     1  1  0  0  0  0  1
59    1  1  0  0  0  0  1
92    1  1  0  0  0  0  1
207   1  1  0  0  0  0  1
211   1  1  0  0  0  0  1
284   1  1  0  0  0  0  1
321   1  1  0  0  0  0  1
387   1  1  0  0  0  0  1
415   1  1  0  0  0  0  1
637   1  1  0  0  0  0  1
....
```